# LINQ to Mocks: accessing method parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

New to the Moq library, I decided to use LINQ to set up the mocks. I have seen plenty of samples that explain how a method's parameter values can be accessed using .Returns when using the "traditional" method of setting up a mock.

But how do you do it with LINQ to Mocks? My code is below which doesn't run, because I can't find a way to name `val`. `val` is supposed to be the value of the second parameter. (`UpdatedValue` is a variable local to the unit test.)

```
IAppSettingLogic MoqAsl = Mock.Of<IAppSettingLogic>(asl => 
    asl.SetAppSettingAsync(AppSettings.LatestReconciliationValue, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) ==
    Task.Run(() => UpdatedValue = val));
```

Comment: Show the method being mocked. I am still unclear on the problem just from the snippet shown.

Comment: For complex scenarios like what you describe, the traditional format is usually used as the linq to mock was more for simple quick setup. Linq to mock does not allow access to parameter values

Comment: public async Task SetAppSettingAsync (string, string, string = null) {...}

Comment: @Nkosi I was afraid of that... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For complex scenarios like what you describe, the traditional format is usually used as the linq to mock was more for simple quick setup. Linq to mock does not allow access to parameter values

```
var UpdateValue = string.Empty;

var mock = new Mock<IAppSettingLogic>();
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.SetAppSettingAsync(AppSettings.LatestReconciliationValue, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns( (string arg0, string val, string args3) => {
        UpdatedValue = val;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

IAppSettingLogic MoqAsl = mock.Object;
```

> LINQ to Mocks is great for quickly stubbing out dependencies that typically don't need further verification. If you do need to verify later some invocation on those mocks, you can easily retrieve them with `Mock.Get(instance)`

Reference [Quickstart: LINQ to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks)

If you have simple members that can be mocked up quicly you can mix the two formats

```
//Ling to Mock
IAppSettingLogic MoqAsl = Mock.Of<IAppSettingLogic>(asl => asl.SimpleMember == someSimpleValue);

//Add traditional setup to get access to return function using "Mock.Get(T)"
Mock.Get(MoqAsl)
    .Setup(_ => _.SetAppSettingAsync(AppSettings.LatestReconciliationValue, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns( (string arg0, string val, string args3) => {
        UpdatedValue = val;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I arrived at. Thanks for the guidance.